# How to combine authenticated() and NOT hasAuthority() in Spring SecurityFilterChain?

Tags: spring-security

In Spring Security 6, I want to set up a `SecurityFilterChain` which checks for a combination of `AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated()` and the negation of a particular `AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority()`.

So I came up with something like that (negation not implemented yet):

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc,
                                       HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    
            .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/secrets/**")).access(
                AuthorizationManagers.allOf(AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated(),
                                            AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("VERY_NAUGHTY")))

            .anyRequest().denyAll())
        .build();
}
```

And now I somehow have to negate the `AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority("VERY_NAUGHTY")` instruction, but I don't know how.

Using `MethodSecurity` this can be done like that:

```java
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() AND !hasAuthority('VERY_NAUGHTY')")
```

Does anybody know how to negate `AuthorityAuthorizationManager.hasAuthority()`? Or is there another way to combine a white- and black-list approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`WebExpressionAuthorizationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.8.8/api/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebExpressionAuthorizationManager.html), see [Migrate SpEL expressions to AuthorizationManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_migrate_spel_expressions_to_authorizationmanager):

> **Migrate SpEL expressions to AuthorizationManager**
>
> For authorization rules, Java tends to be easier to test and maintain than SpEL. As such, `authorizeHttpRequests` does not have a method for declaring a `String` SpEL.
>
> Instead, you can implement your own `AuthorizationManager` implementation or use `WebExpressionAuthorizationManager`.
>
> [...]
>
> Or you can use WebExpressionAuthorizationManager in the following way:
>
> ```java
> http
>     .authorizeRequests((authorize) -> authorize
>         .filterSecurityInterceptorOncePerRequest(true)
>         .mvcMatchers("/complicated/**").access(
>           new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("hasRole('ADMIN') || hasAuthority('SCOPE_read')")
>         )
>         // ...
>         .anyRequest().denyAll()
>     )
>     // ...
> ```